# Proving Convergence of a Certain Recursion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I am trying to prove that for $a\in (0,\infty)$ and $x_{0}\in (0,\infty)$ that the recursion defined by

\begin{equation*}
x_{n+1} := \frac{a}{1+x_{n}}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(n\in \mathbb{N})
\end{equation*}

converges in $\mathbb{R}$, and determine the limit of that recursive sequence. I find that if the sequence is indeed convergent in $\mathbb{R}$, the limit is characterized by

\begin{equation*}
x^{*} = \frac{a}{1+x^{*}} \implies x^{*} = \frac{1}{2}\left(-1+\sqrt{1+4a}\right).
\end{equation*}

I have run into trouble in actually proving the convergence of the sequence, though. Somehow, it seems like the subsequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$ are monotone and bounded and hence convergent (even to the same limit). I'm unsure if this is a productive line of reasoning.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Small MathJax tip: the command `\quad` produces a space more efficiently than typing `\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,`.

Comment: @theo-bendit, that surely qualifies as "any help," so I appreciate it!